# SQL Server : column prefix does not match with a table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query. I keep getting the same error

> The column prefix 'A' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

although the query seems right to me

```
Declare @date1 nvarchar(50) = '2015-12-31'
Declare @date2 nvarchar(50) = '2016-03-31'

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = 
     N'SELECT financial_element_name, financial_structure_value, [' + @date2 + '] , [' + @date1 + ']
       FROM (SELECT A.[financial_structure_value], A.financial_structure_id,
                    A.financial_analysis_session_id, A.period
             FROM counterparty_financial_structure A
             INNER JOIN financial_analysis_session FAS ON FAS.financial_analysis_session_id = A.financial_analysis_session_id
             WHERE A.counterparty_id = 8736) AS Source_table
        PIVOT  
             (max(A.[financial_structure_value]) for A.period in (['+@date2+'] , ['+@date1+']) ) AS PivotTable;'

EXEC (@query)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot is on the subquery, which is called `source_table`, so the problem is this line:

```
PIVOT  (max(A.[financial_structure_value]) for A.period in (['+@date2+'] , ['+@date1+']) ) AS PivotTable;
```

You can just use:

```
PIVOT  (max([financial_structure_value]) for period in (['+@date2+'] , ['+@date1+']) ) AS PivotTable;
```

Note:  When you have errors with dynamic SQL, if you print out the SQL after variable substitution, you'll be able to easily spot the error about 95% of the time.